# Can malochim be human?

Tags: malach-angel, free-will-bechira

The word *malach* technically means "messenger", as in a messenger/agent of Hashem.  Does that mean that a *malach* necessarily has to be a supernatural being, or can it be a human, possibly even someone who isn't aware that they have been put in a place to do something that Hashem has decided that they should do?  I'm not suggesting that they are being forced to do it - it may be entirely in character for them to do so.

I've heard in the past a discussion about free will, that if eg. someone wants to go and murder someone, they will only be successful if the person deserves to be murdered - otherwise it could be that eg. they are hit by a car on the way, or even stuck in traffic, or someone else is killed who does deserve it etc.  However, this sort of thing could apply to a lot of other situations.

eg. If we have a situation where person A is in a difficult position and Hashem decides to send help, He may decide that person B, who is the sort of person who always goes out of their way to help people and is quite capable of helping A with this just happens to end up in the right place at the right time.  Is person B a *malach* of Hashem then?  Does it actually have any practical bearing on anything if we call them one?

Comment: In Mevo HaShearim, it tells that a angel cannot be a human in any sense. It can, however, appear in human-form.

Comment: @Shmuel what about Metatron?

Comment: @RabbiKaii he said angels can't be human, not that humans can't become angels.  Alternatively, maybe the author of Mevo HaShearim doesn't agree that Metatron was originally human.  I would have gone with Eliyahu as another possibility though as well, since he does seem to get referred to in the context of things that we'd expect a malach to be doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *malach* in general can mean anything that acts on behalf of השם by carrying out His command or will.

A standard מלאך השם without other qualifying context is typically viewed to be some supernatural/spiritual creation of השם that He commands and acts on His behalf.

On the other hand, there are a number of instances in Tanach where a מלאך can be a person who is a **נביא, כהן or חכם** (*prophet, priest or sage*) and sometimes a single person who fits more than one or even fits all of the above descriptions. These human מלאכים are typically acting in the service of השם in a conscious way and not in an accidental way.  In some other instances, even other creations of השם are described as His מלאכים.

***Let's see the examples:***

**-----נביא-----**

In **חגי א:יג** it says re: Chagai the *navi*:

> וַיֹּאמֶר **חַגַּי מַלְאַךְ ה' בְּמַלְאֲכוּת ה'** לָעָם לֵאמֹר
> אֲנִי אִתְּכֶם נְאֻם ה

In **מסכת דרך ארץ זוטא**, it comments on that pasuk:

> א״ר יהושע **הנביא נקרא מלאך והחכם נקרא מלאך. הנביא נקרא מלאך שנאמר (חגי
> א׳:י״ג) ויאמר חגי מלאך יי׳**. והחכם נקרא מלאך שנאמר (מלאכי ב׳:ז׳) מלאך
> יי׳ צבאות הוא: יכול יהא כהן עם הארץ ת״ל (שם) ותורה יבקשו מפיהו :

In **מדרש תנחומא פרשת שלח** it reiterates the idea that a *navi* is considered a *malach*:

> וְכֵן הוּא אוֹמֵר, וַיֹּאמֶר **חַגַּי מַלְאַךְ ה' בְּמַלְאֲכוּת ה'** לָעָם
> לֵאמֹר (חגי א, יג). הָא לָמַדְתָּ, **שֶׁנִּקְרְאוּ הַנְּבִיאִים**
> **מַלְאָכִים**

Likewise, the **Radak** comments on that pasuk, that in addition to Chagai acting as a מלאך, Moshe had acted as a מלאך:

> ויאמר, מלאך ה' במלאכות ה'. **שליח ה'** וכן כל מלאך פי' ברוב שליח וכן "וישלח
> **מלאך** ויוציאנו ממצרים" אמר על **משה רבינו** ע"ה:

A midrashic support for a *navi* being referred to as a *malach* presents itself in **שופטים ב:א** regarding **פינחס הכהן**:

> ...וַיַּעַל **מַלְאַךְ ה'** מִן הַגִּלְגָּל אֶל הַבֹּכִים

Where **תרגום יונתן** states:

> וּסְלִיק **נְבִיָא** בִּשְׁלִיחוּת מִן קֳדָם השם

And expanded upon by **Rashi**:

> ויעל מלאך ה'. שנינו ב'סדר עולם' (פרק יט): **זה היה פנחס**:

*(Further support for this can be seen in מדרש תנחומא פרשת שלח)*

**-----כהן-----**

The primary support for this is the pasuk in **מלאכי ב:ז**:

> כִּי שִׂפְתֵי **כֹהֵן** יִשְׁמְרוּ דַעַת וְתוֹרָה יְבַקְשׁוּ מִפִּיהוּ
> **כִּי מַלְאַךְ ה' צְבָאוֹת הוּא**

Upon which **Rashi** comments:

> כי מלאך. **שלוחו של הקב"ה כמלאכי השרת** לשרת לפניו וליכנס לפנים במחיצתו:

And **Ibn Ezra**:

> **מלאך שליח השם** הוא בינו ובין ישראל.

And **Radak**:

> כי מלאך ה' צבאות הוא. כי **הוא שליח האל יתברך** להורות דברי האל לישראל
> ותרגם יונתן ארי משמש קדם ה' צבאות הוא:

I have seen some re-enforce this idea with what is hinted to in **זכריה ג:ז** where **יהושע כהן גדול** is being told that he has the potential to walk as equals among **הָעֹמְדִים הָאֵלֶּה** which refer to the *malachim* metioned in the same perek:

> כֹּה אָמַר ה' צְבָאוֹת אִם בִּדְרָכַי תֵּלֵךְ וְאִם אֶת מִשְׁמַרְתִּי
> תִשְׁמֹר וְגַם אַתָּה תָּדִין אֶת בֵּיתִי וְגַם תִּשְׁמֹר אֶת חֲצֵרָי
> **וְנָתַתִּי לְךָ מַהְלְכִים בֵּין הָעֹמְדִים הָאֵלֶּה**

Additionally, there are midrashim which write that the vision of ascending and descending **מלאכים** that Yaakov saw (בראשית כח:יב) was actually a prophecy to the future of **כהנים** ascending and descending **the ramp to the מזבח** in the בית המקדש:

> וַיַּחֲלֹם וְהִנֵּה סֻלָּם מֻצָּב אַרְצָה וְרֹאשׁוֹ מַגִּיעַ
> הַשָּׁמָיְמָה וְהִנֵּה **מַלְאֲכֵי אֱלֹהִים עֹלִים וְיֹרְדִים בּוֹ**

**ספרי במדבר פרשת קרח - קיט**

> "ויחלום והנה סולם מוצב ארצה" – זה בית המקדש. "וראשו מגיע השמימה" – אלו
> הקרבנות קריבים שריחם עולה לשמים. "והנה **מלאכי אלהים** עולים ויורדים בו" –
> **אלו כהנים המשרתים שעולים ויורדים בַּכֶּבֶשׁ**.

**ילקוט שמעוני**

> והנה מלאכי אלהים, **אלו כהנים גדולים** (ס"א ל"ג גדולים). עולים ויורדים בו,
> **שהיו עולים ויורדים בכבש**

This notion makes its presence felt in our *tefila* as we see the wording in the  *piyut* for Hoshana Rabba:

> אנא אל נא הושענא והושיעה נא אבינו אתה....למען תמים בדורותיו....**למען שמחו כמלאכי מרומים
> הלובש אורים ותומים**. מצווה להביא לבית קדשי
> הקדשים דם ושמן ברחיצת מים. לחולת אהבה. הושענא

**-----חכם-----**

See the aforementioned **מסכת דרך ארץ זוטא** re:

> א״ר יהושע הנביא נקרא מלאך **והחכם נקרא מלאך**. הנביא נקרא מלאך שנאמר (חגי
> א׳:י״ג) ויאמר חגי מלאך יי׳. **והחכם נקרא מלאך** שנאמר (מלאכי ב׳:ז׳) מלאך
> יי׳ צבאות הוא: יכול יהא כהן עם הארץ ת״ל (שם) **ותורה יבקשו מפיהו** :

**-----Inanimate objects such as the stars and constellations and wind-----**

In **תהלים קג:כ** it says (*re: stars and constellations*):

> בָּרְכוּ ה' **מַלְאָכָיו גִּבֹּרֵי כֹחַ** עֹשֵׂי דְבָרוֹ לִשְׁמֹעַ
> בְּקוֹל דְּבָרוֹ

Whereupon in **ברכות י עמוד א**:

> יָצָא לַאֲוִיר הָעוֹלָם וְנִסְתַּכֵּל **בְּכוֹכָבִים וּמַזָּלוֹת**
> וְאָמַר שִׁירָה, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״בָּרְכוּ ה׳ **מַלְאָכָיו גִּבֹּרֵי
> כֹחַ** עוֹשֵׂי דְבָרוֹ לִשְׁמֹעַ בְּקוֹל דְּבָרוֹ בָּרְכוּ ה׳ כָּל
> צְבָאָיו וְגוֹ׳״.

And in **תהלים קד:ד** it says (*re: wind*):

> עֹשֶׂה **מַלְאָכָיו רוּחוֹת** מְשָׁרְתָיו אֵשׁ לֹהֵט

**Rashi:**

> עושה מלאכיו רוחות. עושה את **הרוחות שלוחיו**:

**Ibn Ezra:**

> עושה, **רוחות - הם מלאכיו**, כדרך ורוח סערה עושה דברו.

**Radak:**

> רוחות. **הרוחות הנושבות הם מלאכיו ושלוחיו** כי אין דבר במקרה אלא הכל
> בכוונת המכוין, וכן אש לוהט. והוא האשים והברקים הרצים הכל הוא בדברו
> ובמצותו וכולם משרתי

Comment: Great answer and very thorough, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

"Angels" per se are not humans, but the Ramban in fact says exactly your point -- G-d can put the right person in the right place at the right time.

[Ramban, Genesis 37:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.37.15?lang=he&with=Ramban&lang2=en) You can read the whole piece there (Hebrew or English) but here's the money quote. Joseph is looking for his brothers and gets lost, and "a man" helps him out:

> כי זמן לו הקב"ה מורה דרך שלא מדעתו להביאו בידם ולזה נתכוונו רבותינו (ב"ר פד יד) באמרם כי האישים האלה הם מלאכים

> That G-d had summoned for Joseph an unwitting guide ... and that is what our Sages intended when they said [in the Midrash] that such people were "angels."

Ramban is saying the guy who offered Joseph directions was flesh-and-blood, born and died, literally "a man", as the verse says; but G-d put him in the right place a the right time. The midrash is non-literal, but driving home that point.

I heard one rabbi mention this Ramban with regards to a teacher of his who helped set him on a different course in life.

Comment: Consider חנוך בן ירד, the father of מתושלח, who became the Angel מטטרון שר הפנים. Also take note that מתושלח has the connotation of being the Angel of Death. The flood of Noach, which ended all life, was delayed until the end of his Shiva.